# g++ "declaration of "operator<<" as non-function"

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading

We have a custom Logging class which compiles fine in VisualStudio 2010, but throws errors when being compiled with g++ on Linux. The error message we receive are the following:

```
Logger.hpp:84: error: declaration of "operator<<" as non-function
Logger.hpp:84: error: expected ";" before "(" token
Logger.hpp:91: error: expected ";" before "inline"
Logger.hpp:91: error: declaration of "operator<<" as non-function
Logger.hpp:91: error: expected ";" before "(" token
Logger.hpp:98: error: expected ";" before "typedef"
```

The respective lines of code are the following:

```
/*:84*/inline Logger& operator<<(std::_Smanip<std::ios_base::fmtflags> output)
{
        if (this->loggingEnabled())
                std::cout << output;
        return *this;
}

inline Logger& operator<<(std::_Smanip<std::streamsize> output)
{
        if (this->loggingEnabled())
                std::cout << output;
        return *this;
}

typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*StdEndl)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&);
inline Logger& operator<<(StdEndl output)
{
        if (this->loggingEnabled())
                std::cout << output;
        return *this;
}
```

Other methods overloading the `<<` operator work fine, therefore my guess is that the errors have something to with the argument type (`std::_Smanip`); any clues as to why?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What is the $ sign doing here?

Comment: Sorry, copy&paste error, fixed now.

Comment: Names beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for implementation-specific details, so `std::_Smanip` is probably VS-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_Smanip` is a Microsoft extension, and not part of the standard library. That's why your code compiles under Visual C++.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5858a50%28VS.90%29.aspx) an MSDN article on the use of `_Smanip`, and [here's](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/272659/1177739#post1177739) another one of how to avoid using it and write portable code instead.

**EDIT**: Found another [link](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/33-3.html) that explains manipulators with parameters in great detail. They discuss methods to implement custom ones as well.

Comment: Thanks for the links; I don't see how the 2nd one applies exactly -- I basically just want to pass any std stream manipulators (like formatting) onto my Logging stream...

Comment: @Ben: That was just to show the concept behind `_Smanip`. Couldn't you change `inline Logger& operator<<(std::_Smanip<std::ios_base::fmtflags> output)` to `inline Logger& operator<<(std::ios_base::fmtflags flags)` and then call `std::cout << std::setf( flags )` within the function? Not sure how to fix the other 2.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix it. In the function it's `std::cout.setf(flags)` though.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error message here is a little confusing, but the problem seems to be that `_Smanip` is not defined in GCC's libstdc++ (or at least it's not in my install of 4.6.0). Recall that in C++, any symbol starting with _ and a capital letter, or two __, represent implementation-reserved symbols, in this case what appears to be a VC extension. A related post to the gcc mailing list, suggesting that `smanip` was at one point in the C++98 draft, but later removed (and thus also removed from GCC's C++ runtime, which tends to track the ISO standard fairly strictly) - http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-10/msg00385.html

You'll have to modify the code to use a different technique for GCC. Looking at libstdc++'s implementation of `<iomanip>` will probably help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message really isn't very helpful at all on this. As pointed out by the other answers, _Smanip isn't an official part of the standard library, but I stumbled across this question due to the underlying problem.

Since _Smanip isn't a defined type, the **GCC compiler (even in the latest versions) seems to interpret the definition of operator overloads (with parameters of undefined type) as declarations of class members**. I happened to discover this by forgetting to include the template parameters for the base class when providing a derived class overload. Since the template parameters are part of the type name, what I was specifying as the parameter's type wasn't actually a defined type.

Just figured I'd share that for anyone else coming across this question. The solution is, of course, to make sure that your parameters have fully declared types when providing the declaration for the operator overload.

Comment: Very useful.  It would be nice if g++ had error messages that did not require an interpreter standing in front of the Delphic Oracle.